# How to set up VPN on debian 8.1

Tags: debian, networkmanager, vpn

I have been trying to set up a VPN connection by following the instruction on [zpn.im](https://zpn.im/)

but after restarting the network-manager by typing `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart` and going to create a vpn connection, there is no choice of vpn available. The window that appears after pressing the Add button of network connection's dialog box is as follows : [image]

I wonder what a VPN plugin is and how to find and install the appropriate one to fix my problem. Any help or ideas are most appreciated.

Comment: I tried to install the plugins by using the package manager, and I now have access to openvpn and PPTP choices. Will try to stablish the connection...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, according to the link below and testing the essay with the situation on my own system, the writer is right about the bug. I think I'm going to go back to wheezy too.

[enter link description here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=121313)